# Laravel URL helper: How to generate a perfect URL with query parameters and hash

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, url-helper, laravel-helper

Suppose the route is like this:

```
Route::get('messages/{messages}', ['as' => 'messages.show', 'uses' => 'MessagesController@show']);
```

So, when we will create an URL using URL helper of Laravel,

```
{{ route('messages.show', 12) }}
```

will display `example.com/messages/12`.

This is correct. Let's have some hash in the URL.

```
{{ route('messages.show', [12, '#reply_23']) }}
```

This will display `example.com/messages/12#reply_23`.

This looks good. Now let's add some query strings instead of the hash.

```
{{ route('messages.show', [12, 'ref=email']) }}
```

This will display `example.com/messages/12?ref=email`. This looks cool.

Now add both query string and hash.

```
{{ route('messages.show', [12, 'ref=email', '#reply_23']) }}
```

Now this will display `example.com/messages/12?ref=email&#reply_23`. This looks little ugly because of the `&` in the URL. However it's not creating a lot of problem, I would like to get a clean URL like `example.com/messages/12?ref=email#reply_23`. Is there a way to get rid of the unnecessary `&` in the URL?

**Edit:**
There is a workaround, but I am looking for a solid answer.

```
<a href="{{ route('messages.show', [12, 'ref=email']) }}#reply_23">Link to view on website</a>
```

Comment: Why not just ``'ref=email' . '#reply_23'`` instead of ``'ref=email', '#reply_23'``?

Comment: Yes, it's also a similar workaround. We can also use `'ref=email#reply_23'`, we don't need the concatenation here.

Answer (score 3):

The Laravel `UrlGenerator` class does not support specifying the `#fragment` part of the URL. The code responsible for building the URL is the following, and you can see it just appends the query string parameters and nothing else:

```php
$uri = strtr(rawurlencode($this->trimUrl(
            $root = $this->replaceRoot($route, $domain, $parameters),
            $this->replaceRouteParameters($route->uri(), $parameters)
        )), $this->dontEncode).$this->getRouteQueryString($parameters);
```

A quick test of your code reveals that the second example you posted:

```
{{ route('messages.show', [12, '#reply_23']) }}
```

Actually generates:

```
/messages/12?#reply_23 // notice the "?" before "#reply_23"
```

So it treats `#reply_23` as a parameter rather than as a fragment.

An alternative to this shortcoming would be to write a custom helper function that allows to pass the fragment as a third parameter. You could create a file `app/helpers.php` with your custom function:

```
function route_with_fragment($name, $parameters = array(), $fragment = '', $absolute = true, $route = null)
{
    return route($name, $parameters, $absolute, $route) . $fragment;
}
```

Then add the following line at the end of your `app/start/global.php` file:

```
require app_path().'/helpers.php';
```

You can then use it like this:

```
{{ route_with_fragment('messages.show', [12, 'ref=email'], '#reply_23') }}
```

Of course you can name the function whatever you want, if you feel the name I gave it is too long.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It generates `/messages/12?#reply_23` but when you access the URL, Laravel changes it to `/messages/12#reply_23` automatically.

Comment: Indeed, but the fact remains there is no support for what you are trying to achieve with the `route` helper function. I've updated my answer with an alternative solution.

Comment: Yes, this solution is a cleaner one than other workarounds. Thank you.